# Free Open Source Profiling (Eclipse TPTP): how to profile an application on glassfish server?

Tags: open-source, glassfish, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I want to have a free Open Source profiling tool for an application that is run in Glassfish server. I develop my application on Eclipse so I'm thinking TPTP is a good alternative. Glassfish is an external server to Eclipse and that's why the tool cannot be used directly to the code (at least I suppose). So I would like to know how you can use TPTP with a program on Glassfish.

Comment: I'll try following tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/conferences/eclipseCon2009/712_ProfilingTestingTPTP.pdf) so that I add the environment variables to the JVM options on Glassfish.

Comment: Exact place of settings is `JVM Classpath Settings`-> `Server Classpath`

Comment: I gave up and changed to a commercial solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/download/) beat OpenSource (this time)

Comment: YourKit beats OpenSource because it was so easy to install and use. I searched a lot for free Open Source solutions but commercial people had made the thing best this time. Until using too much time on searhing OpenSource it was worth of using some money to commercial version than waste money on working with Open Source.